# Problem with mesh after using Boolean Modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers

After i apply the Boolean Modifier to cut a hole in my phone the surface of phone become stretched and some black shadows appear.

[image: black shadows]

[image: other angle]

Thanks!

Comment: These are smooth shading artifacts caused by bad topology. While Bevel or Edge Split modifier might fix that visually (and might not, depending on the case) it would be better to convert all Ngons and tiny quads into proper topology made of evenly distributed quads. This isn't an easy task though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using smooth shading. This can be fixed by switching to flat shading or using a bevel modifier.